# Kendo tooltip showing error in console

Tags: kendo-ui

I have written a code for a kendo tooltip and it is showing an error like this -

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method
>   'kendoTooltip'

It is an editable listview in a kendowindow.

Here is the code

```
<span style="float: right; margin-top: 4px;">
        <a id="mortgage_add_row" href="#"><img src="<?php echo STATIC_DIR; ?>images/icon7.png" alt="" height="36" width="37"></a>
        <a id="mortgage_delete_row" href="#"><img src="<?php echo STATIC_DIR; ?>images/icon8.png" alt="" height="36" width="37"></a>
        <a id="mortgage_edit_row" class="k-edit" href="#"><img src="<?php echo STATIC_DIR; ?>images/icon9.png" alt="" height="36" width="37"></a>
        <a id="mortgage_save_row" class="k-insert" href="#"><img src="<?php echo STATIC_DIR; ?>images/icon10.png" alt="" height="36" width="37"></a>
    </span><div class="clear"></div>
```

These all links are CRUD buttons and they are bound to the respective actions.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Other code.

// Add Row
        $("#mortgage_add_row").on("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            mortage_listview.add();
        });

        // Delete Row
        $("#mortgage_delete_row").on("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            mortage_listview.remove(mortage_listview.element.children().first());
            if (dataSource.total() < 1) {
                mortage_listview.add();
            } else {
                dataSource.read();
            }
        });

        // edit row
        $("#mortgage_edit_row").on("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            mortage_listview.edit(mortage_listview.element.children().first());
        });

        // save row
        $("#mortgage_save_row").on("click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            mortage_listview.save();
        });

        if (!kendoWindow_mortgage.data("kendoWindow")) {
            kendoWindow_mortgage.kendoWindow({
                width: "520px",
                title: ""
            });
        }

        $("#mortgage_add_row").kendoTooltip({
            content: "Hello!"
        });

});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version (release) of KendoUI are you using? AFAIK it was introduced in 2013.1.319, is this the one that you are using?

Comment: Thanks, yes, it was an older version. :)

Comment: If you have found the solution to your problem, please post the solution and accept your own answer.  It is helpful so that people do not waste time reading over a question that has already been answered.

Comment: The reason for this problem was the old kendo version. I also had another problem related to the version, and it was the center method of the KendoWindow was not working. So, if you find anything not working make sure about the kendo version.